# Azure website creation gives "Access denied"

Tags: git, deployment, command-line, azure, web

I am using the azure command line tools for Mac (`version 0.6.2 of the tools, 1.0.1 of the azure tools installer for MacOS`) and I am trying to create a website with a git repository using : `azure site create MyUniqueApp --git`.

I keep seeing this :

```
$ azure site create MyUniqueApp --git
info:    Executing command site create
+ Enumerating locations                                                        
+ Enumerating sites                                                            
info:    Updating existing site
+ Retrieving user information                                                  
error:   Access is denied.
error:   site create command failed
```

Running the same command without the `--git` option is successful.

```
$ azure site create MyUniqueApp
info:    Executing command site create
+ Enumerating locations                                                        
+ Enumerating sites                                                            
info:    Using location North Europe
info:    Creating a new web site at MyUniqueApp.azurewebsites.net
+ Sending site information                                                     
info:    Created website at myuniqueapp.azurewebsites.net
info:    Initializing remote Azure repository
+ Updating site information                                                    
info:    Repository initialized
+ Retrieving site information                                                  
info:    To create a local git repository to publish to the remote site, please rerun this command with the --git flag: "azure site create MyUniqueApp --git".
info:    site create command OK
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you downloaded and imported a publishsettings file for your account?

Comment: account download and account import would be my call too. My bet is on redhotvengeance. (That was just fun to say)

Comment: RHV that probably should be posted as an answer for future vistors.

Comment: I did use `azure account download` and `azure account import. Notice that the command works if I don't specify `--git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are experiencing a temporary issue that should be resolved soon. For more information, see my blog post here: http://hashtagfail.com/post/31636752900/azure-site-create-bug.